# Выбрать последние 100 по дате postgres

Tags: postgresql

есть данные в таблице postgres 9.3.3 хранятся в виде timestamp. как выбрать последние 100 (10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10